# How to conditionally show list items in React based on screen size

Tags: javascript, reactjs, responsive-design

I am trying to create a navigation with a 'more' menu. It seems to be a fairly simple concept.. CBS Sports is an example of it (https://www.cbssports.com/)

Basically show as many links as possible, and push the rest to the dropdown.

Is there a correct approach to implementing this in react? Basically change the count of visible items based on the size of the screen?

I've been trying to find an example of an implementation but am not sure how to find it.

Comment: It would be great if you put some code so we can help you

Comment: useEffect with addEventListener on `resize` event. You could throttle it too to limit number of calls to improve performance. Then pass callback in which you can filter the list of links in nav. For example: `function useResize(callback, delay) {
  useEffect(() => {
    const resizeListener = _.throttle(callback, delay);

    window.addEventListener('resize', resizeListener);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('resize', resizeListener);
    };
  }, []);
}
`

Comment: @Eggy Thanks! I needed this! I think I should then store the variable in state and force a rerender

Answer (score 0):

Changing the count of visible items based on the size of the screen for me is a good idea. You can create variable which give you number of visible items. Later you can map after filtered items from array which contains all items. For example

```
arr.filter((_,i)=> i < number).map(item=> (<li>{item}</li>))
```

and for item which go to dropdown

```
arr.filter((_,i)=> i >= number).map(item=> (<li>{item}</li>))
```